# useForm in React: formState.isDirty is true, but .dirtyFields is empty

Tags: reactjs, use-form

I have a React JS form using `useForm` library.

This is a popular library so I'm not sure this can be a bug but I'm getting into a state which seems incorrect. See the screenshot of the console in chrome below:

[image: Screenshot of console]

How can I have `formState.isDirty`, but no `formState.dirtyFields`?

It's a large, complex form but the isDirty state is achieved by human interaction with the form, with registration looking like this:

```
<input id="value" {...register("value")} defaultValue={variable.value} />
```

One other observation - the behavior seems to change when observed. For example, when adding this code to the form - it seems to work more as expected:

```
<div>
  {formState.isDirty ? "DIRTY" : "CLEAN"}
  <pre>dirty {JSON.stringify(formState.dirtyFields, null, 2)}</pre>
  <pre>touched {JSON.stringify(formState.touchedFields, null, 2)}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Related? [react-hook-form#3213](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/3213)

Comment: Could you also provide the call to useForm() that you used to set formState?

Comment: Added more code, and information

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious now, but the problem was I had a dependency on `formState` in a function called on button click. Because clicking the button doesn't cause a re-render of the form, the fresh value of `formState` is not retrieved from `useForm` - meaning it is stale.

The trick is to have this change trigger a re-render. You can do this by having it in rendered in the output (so .tsx/.jsx spots the dependency) or by using `useCallback` to create the save function and register `formState` in the dependencies of that function, a la

```
const save = useCallback(() => {
// save using formState dirtyFields, touchedFields etc
}, [formState]);

// ...

<button onClick={save} />
```

Now, it works great and this explains the behavior change when showing the dirty state in the HTML output.